# Storybook|React hot reload isn't working v5.1.11

Tags: typescript, storybook

Simple as that, Hot Reload isn't working at all, I follow the exact steps https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/

> .storybook/config.js

```
import { configure } from '@storybook/react';

// automatically import all files ending in *.stories.js
const req = require.context('../stories', true, /\.stories\.js$/);
function loadStories() {
  req.keys().forEach(filename => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

> stories/index.stories.js

```
import React from 'react';

import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links';

import { Button, Welcome } from '@storybook/react/demo';

storiesOf('Welcome', module).add('to Storybasdook', () => <Welcome showApp={linkTo('Button')} />);

storiesOf('Buttasdawon', module)
  .add('with text', () => <Button onClick={action('clicasdawked')}>Hello Button</Button>)
  .add('with some emoji', () => (
    <Button onClick={action('clicked')}>
      <span role="img" aria-label="so cool">
           
      </span>
    </Button>
  ));
```

When I run `yarn storybook` everything works fine, but lets say I want to change `.add('with some emoji'..` to `.add('with some emojiiiiii..'` nothing changes, I need to relaunch `yarn storybook` to see changes

Comment: I am experiencing this as well. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Austin Dude this is some kind of witchcraft, I tried everything, tsconfig, storybook config, webpack config (creating another webpack), everythiiing and nothing, after one whole sprint we decide to "re-do" everything from scratch aka reinstalling and lose everything we did, this is "solve" the problem.

Basically we don't know what happened, so I suggest to re-install everything from scratch guided with official tutorial